Book where you can fall in a loop, an old man becomes young again
It starts with an old man who tries to commit suicide by jumping off a cliff. He is holding some magic type rocks. He falls through the sky. In these books you can keep falling and end up back at the top, and fall again. There's a barrier he goes through and becomes young again. It turns out he used to be an emperor who was overthrown and a complete tyrant

How long ago did you read it?  How old do you think the book is?

Could be David Gemmell's "The Last Guardian" synopsis here: https://davidgemmell.fandom.com/wiki/The_Last_Guardian
Things that match:

Magic stones - the Sipstrassi stones are magic
Old man getting younger - the stones can "heal" aging
Deposed ruler - there’s a reincarnation of a ruler

If not this, the magic stones could indicate another of the books set in the same universe.
